# Hadoop cluster java.net ConnectionException: Connection refused error

Tags: java, hadoop

I used to have a hadoop cluster running with centos 6.5 that was built using a gui. It made everything work perfectly. For a bunch of reasons that are not relevant i needed to upgrade to centos 7. The gui i used to install it on 6.5 just doesnt have centos 7 as an option. As a result I have to manually install it on a new centos 7 cluster. I keep running into this error.

```
Call From Cluster-Client-1/ip.add.ress to Cluster-Client-1:8020 failed on 
connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: 
Connection refused; for more details see the website
```

The relevant port on my cluster is 50010 so i think where it says "cluster-client-1:8020 that it should say 50010 but i dont know where that appropriate file is or how to change it. The ip-address is correct. You probably need more information to answer my question. but I don't know what you need so please ask away. There are currently no slave nodes in the cluster I'm in the process of adding more but i need to solve this error before i can move on.

Please help

Comment: What is this GUI that you used? The only GUIs I've used are Ambari or Cloudera Manager

Comment: What port number is specified in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml? Mine is `<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://<HOSTNAME>:8020</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>`

Comment: It was built into VMware. I'm a student so the IT guy on staff did it the first time around. He has no experience with hadoop. In coresite.xml its 50010

Comment: 50010 is the port for the datanode. 8020 is the port for the namenode. Is the namenode running? What configuration are you running? single node/pseudo-distributed/distributed?

Comment: Right now it is single node. I want to eventually expand it to multiple nodes, but for now single node is enough

Comment: Did you get any further with this? Did you confirm if the namenode was running?